# Read, modify and write using FileHelperAsyncEngine

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am new to FileHelper so bear with me.
I want to read an existing .csv file that has one of the columns with no data.
Next I want to populate that column from a db (the code attached is just putting in a string for now, I'll deal with the db call later)
Then, I want to output the file with the updated column information.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine<Agents>();
        using (engine.BeginReadFile(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\Agents.csv"))
        {
            int pId = 100;

            // The engine is IEnumerable
            foreach (Agents agent in engine)
            {
                agent.PersonID = pId.ToString();
                pId++;
            }
                      engine.BeginWriteFile(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\Output.csv");
        }
    }
```

This reads the file, but only outputs the 1st row (in this case, the header row)
I expect to get the entire updated file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are using the same `FileHelperAsyncEngine` to write output to. You need to open another `FileHelperAsyncEngine`.

What you're doing at `engine.BeginWriteFile` is simply closing the read-stream and opening a write-stream instead.

You probably meant something more like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine<Agents>();
  var outEngine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine<Agents>();

  using (engine.BeginReadFile(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\Agents.csv"))
  using (outEngine.BeginWriteFile(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\Output.csv"))
  {
    int pId = 100;

    // The engine is IEnumerable
    foreach (var record in engine)
    {
      record.PersonID = pId.ToString();
      pId++;

      outEngine.WriteNext(record);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: getting: FileHelpers.FileHelpersException: 'You must call BeginRead before use the engine in a for each loop.' at the foreach ( var record in engine)

Comment: @MichaelDunham: Then you're not doing it right. The above code should work. Although I admit that it's not tested but `using (engine.BeginReadFile(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\Agents.csv"))` does exactly what the error message says: Calls `BeginRead` before the for each loop.

Comment: I would second this.  Because you are not storing the records in a local cache, you need a second engine (which is the most efficient way for this example).  If you were caching the records with the change, you could then use the same engine in a BeginFileWrite loop.  That means the write waits until all records are read though which is less efficient.